# Workflow system resources

Tags: workflow

I am going to have to make a 'workflow system' for my work placement upcoming semester but I don't know what they are and how they work, so I have been asked to learn about them.
Can any of you direct me to some good resources to learn how they work (and possibly how to implement one)?

Comment: What platforms and languages are you currently comfortable with?

Comment: I know java J2SE very well, I'm comfortable with some parts of J2EE (servlets, enterprise beans and javax.persistence).
I'm also quite comfortable with c#.net
I also know some php and c++ although I don't think those will be usefull in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to learn the workflow of where you're going to work, you should contact them and ask. Ideally get in contact with the person who will be in charge of you.

1. Make sure you're comfortable with the concept of [workflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow)
2. Talk to your future boss, identifying workflow steps
3. Model the workflow using some sort of UML
4. Check out [common workflow patterns](http://www.workflowpatterns.com/) to see if any match your model.

Comment: Thats not totally it, I'm going to have to make a workflow system that should be configurable, so that it doesn't only work for one workflow but that you could design new workflows with it later on, or someting like that.

But thanks for the links, they look really usefull.